# In iOS 13.4, SwiftUI ObservedObject in nested ForEach no longer updates View as in iOS 13.3

Tags: ios, swiftui

Here is a simple code to show the problem. It displays a list of name in OberservedObject `data`, which is in nested ForEach. When `data` is updated by clicking the button, the view should be updated. The code works perfectly in iOS 13.3 for both simulators and devices, i.e. the view will be updated after clicking the button. But it fails in iOS 13.4 for both simulators and devices, i.e. the view is never updated. Any idea what's going on here?

```
class Data: ObservableObject {
  @Published var names = ["Alice", "Jason", "Tom"]
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var data = Data()

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
      ForEach(0..<2) { _ in
        ForEach(0..<self.data.names.count) { i in
          Text(self.data.names[i])
        }
      }

      Button(action: { self.data.names[0] = "Mary" }) {
        Text("Click me")
          .padding()
          .border(Color.black, width: 4)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60415844/swiftui-foreach-based-on-state-int/60416515#60416515

Comment: That works! Thank you

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user3441734! The working code is updated as the below.

```
class Data: ObservableObject {
  @Published var names = ["Alice", "Jason", "Tom"]
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var data = Data()

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
      ForEach(0..<2, id: \.self) { _ in
        ForEach(0..<self.data.names.count, id: \.self) { i in
          Text(self.data.names[i])
        }
      }

      Button(action: { self.data.names[0] = "Mary" }) {
        Text("Click me")
          .padding()
          .border(Color.black, width: 4)
      }
    }
  }
}
```